# Please suggest something better than gotoxy function in C++

Tags: c++, console, console-application, cout, windows-console

I have written a program that consists of multiples and multiples of function each of which are printing several things on the console when control is passed to them. Now I am trying to print everything in the center of the screen rather than on the upper left corner of the screen. For that purpose, the only thing I know is the gotoxy function of Windows.h. Now this would be an extremely hectic job because I would have to place gotoxy above each "cout". Is there a way that I set the cursor to a particular position on the screen and every time anything gets printed, the printing commences from that particular position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a small helper function (e.g. printCentered(std::string) ) that receives the string to be printed. This function moves the cursor to the center and then prints the parameter. Then replace your couts with a call to this function.

Comment: `std::string` would arguably be a better choice (or at least `const char *`).

Comment: For implementing this thing, I have to ammend my whole program which I am trying to avoid. Is there any alternative you can suggest?

Comment: I guess one call to awk or sed should do all the editing of your existing code. The other way would be to hook calls to the << over cout, but somebody else would need to tell you if this is (a) possible and (b) how to do it.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Reassigning `cout` (or any standard stream) is most definitely possible, for example I've got code to turn each line written to `cerr` into a messagebox.  But it's a lot of extra work.  Whether or not it's worth it depends on how many lines of code need to be updated to call a centered function instead.

Comment: @Ben Thank you. Also I imagine that this way is a lot more work than passing each C-source through awk or sed.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: It is a lot of work.  Whether it's more work is debatable, since your "fix" will only fix output of simple strings.  There's no regex that will turn `cout << "A = " << hex << 5 << endl;` into a call to `printCentered(string)`.

Comment: Then use sed to enter "gotoxy(100,100);" before each "cout".

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Presumably the correct coordinates depend on the string, i.e. `left = (screen_width - line_length)/2;`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `cout` or any other stream-based I/O for drawing all over the screen. It doesn't make sense to "position" a stream if it's being redirected to a different device.
2. Call the [Win32 console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly, such as [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/15/10090867.aspx) that draws a status line in a console program.

Answer (score 1):

The following allows easy find-and-replace and takes care of setting the cursor to the center:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& PrintCentered(){
  // comment in the following if you're experiencing
  // weird output due to io-buffering like @Ben says in a comment
  //std::cout.flush();
  gotoxy(your_x, your_y);
  return std::cout;
}
```

Now just find&replace your `std::cout` calls with the above function where you want it to be centered. Usage after replace should look like this:

```
PrintCentered() << "your message";
```

Comment: +1: that's why I'm scared of and, at the same thing, fascinated by c++ :P

Comment: Some synchronization is needed, as `cout` is allowed to be buffered.

Comment: `cout << "xyz"; PrintCentered() << "your message";` could result in `gotoxy` followed by outputting "xyzyourmessage", if the "xyz" was buffered instead of printed immediately.  When you want to order output with other function calls, you need to flush the buffers.

Comment: @Ben: Oh, yes, but that problem exists if the OP just inserts the gotoxy calls in his code. One may add a call to `cout.flush()` before gotoxy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using cout to write to, this hack should do the job:

```
 #define AT_CENTER( stuff ) goto( 100, 100 ); cout << stuff;
```

Where 100, 100 should be replaced with your specific values. Then in use:

```
 AT_CENTER( "The meaning of life is " << x );
```

Comment: @Etienne: being an atheist myself, I would still like to quote a certain holy book: "Let he who is without sin cast the first stone" ;)

Comment: Well, for small values of "horrendous". You must be a sensitive soul - there is much worse out there. And I did say it was a hack. And actually I use something very similar in all my error reporting code.